# NX Client behaves differently for GNOME and KDE

Tags: display, fedora, gnome, kde, nx

When using NXClient on KDE (Fedora) to connect to a Ubuntu machine with GNOME, NX works flawlessly, and automatically resizes the display to match the client window. However, when I change the settings to connect with KDE, the display doesn't resize and stays as only a small portion of the display. 
[image]